# How to transfer a data in Binary form via Bluetooth in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am developing a device driver software for iOS and mac. In this I want to transfer a Number data in Binary form from my iPhone App to a device via blutoogh. Suppose I want to transfer a Data like 20 Jan 2013 10:30 am the i need to transfer 200120131030  in a binary sequence. means first binary of 20 then binary of 01 then binary of 2013  and so on...
other device is not running on iOS. 
I convert this number to NSData  but can't understand that NSData is abinary data or not. Is there a way to make it binary and transfer it. (I can transferred data via bluetooth)

Comment: It's all binary and it's all bytes.  The question is how the apps on each end of the pipe interpret bytes.  So you can send a UTF-8 string, that's a sequence of bytes like digit 2, digit 0, digit 0, digit 1 ... etc.  Or, much more compactly, you can send a long integer 200 billion + 120 million, etc.  NSData will let you do either... see methods +dataWithBytes:length: and -bytes.

Comment: Ok I understand what you want to say. But can u explain that UTF-8 encoding and NSData both are same ???

Comment: sure.  will explain in an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you decide to represent the date as a string of 12 digits, or 12 bytes.  You can get NSData this way:

```
NSDate *date = // the date you start with

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYYHHmm"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

// dateString can be any string you wish to send.  In this example, it represents a date
NSData *data = [dateString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can get a pointer to the byte data with the bytes selector on NSData.  Say you want to copy out the data:

```
NSUInteger length = [data length];
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(length);
memcpy(buffer, [data bytes], length);
```

As I mentioned in my comment, a more compact serialization is a long integer.  You can get smaller data like this:

```
unsigned long dateInt = [dateString intValue];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&dateInt length:sizeof(dateInt)];
```

... then get the bytes out the same way.  The important thing to remember is that the sender and receiver of these bytes must agree on how to interpret them.

Comment: ok thanx.
so if there is another number sequence that i want to send like
"1020224589" is our data. Then I use
NSString *valueObj = @"1020224589";
NSData *data =  get data from string "valueObj";
NSUInteger length = [data length];
char * buffer = (char *)malloc(length);
memcpy(buff, [data bytes], length);
and then send this buffer data right???

Comment: Yes.  See where we turn dateString into NSData?  You can do that with any string.  Then memcpy the bytes.

Comment: What actually statement "memcpy(buffer, [data bytes], length)"  do.Pls explain this

Comment: That copies bytes from one location to another.  Destination, source (both c-pointers), and length (in bytes).  I included to illustrate that you have byte formatted data to pass to your communication code.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html